# How to sort my array of objects based on firebase Timestamp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I need my messages should be ordered based on timestamp ("createdAt" is the name of filed) i can do it in earlier versions of firebase but cant fig out how to do it in firebase v9

DATA STRUCTURE ON FIRESTORE

[image: SEE IMAGE HERE]

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {

        const unsub = onSnapshot(doc(db, "messages", state.id), (snapshot) => {
            if(snapshot.data()){
                console.log(123,Object.values(snapshot.data()))
                setMessages(Object.values(snapshot.data()))
            }
        });
    }, [])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have in your document is not an array. They are just fields with random IDs. You can sort them using `.sort()` as shown below:

```
if (snapshot.data()) {
  const sortedMessages = Object.values(snapshot.data()).sort((a, b) => a.createdAt.toMillis() - b.createdAt.toMillis())

  setMessages(sortedMessages);
}
```

Comment: This is working and doing the job but its crashes after each msg is sent 

ERROR : TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toMillis')

Comment: @ArnabKumar that means `createdAt` field is missing from the document. Are you sure that field is present ? Also just `.sort((a, b) => a.createdAt - b.createdAt)` should do it iirc.

Comment: Yes 100% sure it is present

Comment: @ArnabKumar can you `console.log(snapshot.data())` before this sort function and share the output to ensure that?

Comment: its working after removing the .toMilis()

Comment: Firebase timestamps can be compared JS comparison operators. This was added in [v7.10.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#7.10.0) so `toMillis()` shouldn't be necessary